# SPSite in web service throws 401 error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sharepoint, wss-3.0

I have this code:

```
using ( var site = new SPSite( myUrl ) ) {
    using ( var web = site.AllWebs[0] ) {
        // read-only operations
    }
}
```

The "myUrl" is top domain url with WSS 3.0. The authentication is set to Windows.
If I run this code from command-line under "external_app_user" account, all is fine. But if I run this code from webservice (outside of WSS webapplication), then result is http response "401 UNAUTHORIZED" instead of SOAP response. It's odd, because this code is in "try-catch" block, and if is any excception thrown I returned own error message in SOAP response.

The code is running on the same machine as WSS.

If I run the webservice from webbroser on the machine where web service is running, the classic windows login form is shown. If I run the webservice from webbrowser on another computer, I get only "401 UNAUTHORIZED" http response.

The web service is running under correct account. This account has access to the WSS (tested via sharepoint website). If i try get "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name" the correct username is returned.

In web.config is set "<identity impersonate="true" userName="_my_username_" password="_my_password_" />.

Anyone has idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: http://solutionizing.net/2009/01/06/elegant-spsite-elevation/

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you cannot catch the 401 is because SharePoint has custom handling for this exception, see this thread: [Cannot catch the SharePoint Access denied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724679/cannot-catch-the-sharepoint-access-denied-error) (including a suggestion how to turn it off).

Answer (score 1):

You could check in IIS if both Anonymous and Windows Authentication is allowed. Then it may be allowing you through as anonymous, instead of reading your windows identity, which leads to an unauthorized later.

Comment: Anonymous and Windows Authentication is allowed.
Now I get stacktrace, and the 401 UNAUTHORIZED error is getting from "AllWebs" property on get.